# Red Hat Linux 7.0 Password is expired after break the password

Tags: command-line, rhel, passwd

I break a Red Hat Linux 7.0 password for learning purpose. But when it comes to login screen and after enter the password, it shows as "**Password is expired**".

These steps are used for break the password.

1. In boot up menu press e for go to **edit mode**.
2. Then after add **`rd.break`** command.
3. Exit that mode using **Ctrl+X**.
4. `mount -o remount,rw /sysroot`
5. `chroot /sysroot`
6. `chage -E -l root`
7. `passwd root`
8. Add a root password.
9. `touch /.autorelabel`
10. Type **`exit`** twice.

Please advice to solve this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think `chage -E` without specifying `EXPIRE_DATE` might be setting number of days till expiration to zero.
Try:

```
chage -E -1 root
```

From `man chage`:

> Passing the number -1 as the EXPIRE_DATE will remove an account expiration date.

Verify with:

```
chage -l root
```

Please specify what bootloader you're using. If it's `GRUB`, you can boot into single-user mode by adding `1` or `single` at the end of an entry you're editing. This should allow logging as root without password.